# How to change string to html format?

Tags: python, html, django

I develop a django project.

I want to show output string on html.

My view is :

```
def strategy_run(request):
    output = "hello world!\nstring test"
    return render_to_response('strategy_run.html', locals())
```

My strategy_run.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
{{output}}
</body>
</html>
```

But I want the html showing like:

```
hello world!
string test
```

Their html might be `"hello world!<br>string test"`.

So How to change string to html format?

Is there a python or django function for changing the format?

Thank you.

Comment: by puttin a <br/> where you put \n

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but it sounds like you might want the `linebreaks` or `linebreaksbr` [template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-linebreaks).

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to do this.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def strategy_run(request):
     return HttpResponse("hello world!<br>string test")
```

2nd

```
def strategy_run(request):
    output = "hello world!<br>string test"
    return render_to_response('strategy_run.html', locals())
```

3rd in your stragegy_run.html only

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
{{ output|linebreaksbr }}
</body>
</html>
```